# Parsing xml using Kafka + Spark Streaming to Oracle database

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark to read streaming data from a kafka topic (messages are xml records), then convert the parsing into a dataframe so that it can be inserted into an Oracle database table as a stream. I used the ElementTree library to build a function that returns them to data_list form but don't know how to apply it to the spark dataframe obtained from kafka before. Here is some of my code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,udf, to_json, from_json, expr,explode, arrays_zip, col
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType, ArrayType,StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd`

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FBNK_ACCOUNT").config("spark.local.dir", "D:/test").getOrCreate()
# Cấu hình Kafka
kafka_params = {
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",  # Địa chỉ Kafka broker
    "subscribe": "my_topic",                      # Tên topic Kafka để subscribe
    "startingOffsets": "latest"                    # Thiết lập offset reset cho consumer group
}
# Đọc dữ liệu từ Kafka topic "my_topic"
schema = "table STRING, op_type STRING, op_ts STRING, current_ts STRING, pos STRING, after STRUCT<RECID: STRING, XMLRECORD: STRING>"
df1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**kafka_params).load()

df2=df1.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

```
def parse_xml(xml_string):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
    id_value = root.attrib.get('id', None)
    data_list = []
    for child in root:
        data_list.append({"ID": id_value,"COLUMNS": child.tag, "M_SEQ": child.attrib.get("m", "1"), "N_SEQ": child.attrib.get("n", "1"), "VALUE": child.text})
    return data_list
schema = ....
parse_xml_udf = udf(parse_xml,schema)
```

At this point, I don't know how to declare the schema and apply the udf function to get a spark dataframe df3 including the corresponding columns ID, COLUMNS, M_SEQ, N_SEQ and VALUE so that I can insert it into the oracle database to use

```
def write_to_oracle(batch_df, batch_id):
     batch_df.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table="FBNK_ACCOUNT", mode="append", properties=connection_properties)

query = df3.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .foreachBatch(write_to_oracle) \
    .start().awaitTermination()
```

Here is a sample of my input message
`<row id='JPY1944037322310' xml:space='preserve'><c2>19440</c2><c3>INTERNAL ACCOUNT 19440</c3><c4>INTERNAL ACCOUNT 19440</c4><c5>INTERNAL ACCOUNT 19440</c5><c6>INTA066383</c6><c7>TR</c7><c8>JPY</c8 ><c9>1</c9 ><c11>1000</c11 ><c20 m='2'>3732</c20><c76>NO</c76><c78>20150302</c78><c85>19440</c85><c93>JPY</c93><c94>1</c94><c95>JPY</c95><c96>1</c96><c99>LEGACY</c99><c99 m='2'>CARD.ID</c99><c108>NO</c108><c141>NO</c141><c143>I</c143><c203>1</c203><c204>1063_INPUTTER_I_INAU_WS___OFS_DM.OFS.SRC</c204><c205>1506231613</c205><c205 m='2'>1506231613</c205><c206>1063_INPUTTER_WS____OFS_DM.OFS.SRC</c206><c207>VN0012310</c207><c208>1000</c208></row>`

I tried asking ChatGPT but it didn't work. I have successfully handled it when not working with spark streaming, but in this case I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: Where does the XML come from? Why can't you just parse it **before** writing to Kafka? Kafka works best with binary data, not plaintext formats with unnecessary XHTML tags

Comment: _but don't know how to apply it to the spark dataframe_ - Did you search/ask ChatGPT about using your Pyspark UDF? You've cast the value, now `select` with your UDF function.